# Save JPG from CDROM to PC

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using following function to Save the output from SWF and send it to a PHP page so that it creates JPG, my problem if there is not INTERNET connection and the SWF is in a CDROM can the Save function be used in FLASH so that it outputs JPG and save it on a computer.

In short can we Save movieclip output as an JPG

```
  /**
    Screenshot and jpg output
    **/
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.geom.Matrix;

    //Buttons handlers. Should add an extra function because delegate doesn't allow to pass parameters
    shaF.onPress = mx.utils.Delegate.create(this,makeShadow);

    //Helper functions to pass parameters
    function makeShadow() { capture(0) }

    /*
    create a function that takes a snapshot of the Video object whenever it is called
    and shows in different clips
    */
    function capture(nr){
     this["snapshot"+nr] = new BitmapData(abc._width,abc._height); 

     //the bitmap object with no transformations applied
     this["snapshot"+nr].draw(abc,new Matrix());
     var t:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("bitmap_mc"+nr,nr);

     //positions clip in correct place
     //t._x = 350; t._y = 10+(nr*130); t._xscale = t._yscale = 50

     //display the specified bitmap object inside the movie clip
     t.attachBitmap(this["snapshot"+nr],1);
    output(nr);
     //attachMovie("print_but", "bot"+nr, 100+nr, {_x:t._x+t._width+50, _y:t._y+t._height/2}) 
    }
    //Create a new bitmapdata, resize it 50 %, pass image data to a server script
    // using a LoadVars object (large packet)
    function output(nr){
      //Here we will copy pixels data
      var pixels:Array = new Array()
      //Create a new BitmapData
      var snap = new BitmapData(this["snapshot"+nr].width, this["snapshot"+nr].height); 
      //Matrix to scale the new image
      myMatrix = new Matrix();
      myMatrix.scale(1, 1)


      //Copy image
      snap.draw(this["snapshot"+nr],  myMatrix);

      var w:Number = snap.width, tmp
      var h:Number = snap.height
      //Build pixels array
      for(var a=0; a<=w; a++){
       for(var b=0; b<=h; b++){
        tmp = snap.getPixel32(a, b).toString(16)
        //if(tmp == "-fcffff")
        //{
         //tmp="-ff0000";
        //}

        pixels.push(tmp.substr(1))
       }
      }
      //Create the LoadVars object and pass data to PHP script
      var output:LoadVars = new LoadVars()
      output.img = pixels.toString()
      output.height = h
      output.width = w
      //The page (and this movie itself) should be in a server to work
      output.send("show.php", "output", "POST")    
    }
    stop()
```

Comment: Client side saving is enabled for FP 10 and up, previous versions of FP require a round-trip to a server.  The answers below leave out this information but should otherwise both be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the `BitmapData`, this is fairly easy. Modifying your `output` function:

```
//Copy image
snap.draw(this["snapshot"+nr],  myMatrix); 

//Now check if we want to save as JPG instead of sending data to the server
if (runningFromCdrom) {
    var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
    var bytes:ByteArray = encoder.encode(snap);
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(bytes);
} else {
    // ...the rest of your output method...
}
```

How to determine the `runningFromCdrom` value is up to you. If the SWF is being run inside an HTML document, the best way to tell if the program is being run from a CD-ROM would be to specify it in the FlashVars.

Comment: I am getting this error after  use your code 

stop()

Total ActionScript Errors: 5   Reported Errors: 5

Comment: That doesn't help identify the error. Does it happen when you compile the code, or when you run it? Why does the error mention `stop()`? If calling that worked before it should still work now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can save JPEG's directly from Flash. There is no need for the intermediate step to PHP.

You can use one of these JPEG encoders:

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-tutorial-an-asynchronous-jpeg-encoder

I would recommend the second as it can work asynchronously (kind of) which means your UI shouldn't lock up while encoding the JPEG.